# Set log name in appender of log4net

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration

I have class MyLogger, where I use log4net. How can I modify my appender to save log in specific logname (I want to set it by parameter logName).

```
public void AddEntry(string source, string logName, string contextInfo, string message, EventLogEntryType eventType)
        {

             log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(source);

             Log.Error(String.Format("Context Info: {0}{1}{2}{3}", contextInfo, Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine, message));

        }

<log4net>
  <root>
    <priority value="ALL" />
     <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
  </root>
```

This is myAppender. Now it writes in common logtype Application.

```
  <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >

    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%logger (%property{myContext}) [%level]- %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

Comment: Is `logName` global to the application, or do you want to be able to change it at runtime?

Comment: I want to change it at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this works:

```
<param name="LogName" type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogName}" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this:

```
<param name="LogName" value="MyLog" />
```

Some more information can be found [here](http://geekswithblogs.net/TimH/archive/2006/04/13/75063.aspx). If you do something like this you may want to have a look at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412463/description-for-event-id-from-source-cannot-be-found/3414029#3414029) as well. Basically this is about registering your application so that the eventlog knows about it.

**Edit** (configuration by code):

Did not test it but that ought to do the trick:

```
foreach (AppenderSkeleton appender in this.Logger.Repository.GetAppenders())
{
    var eventlogAppender = appender as EventLogAppender;
    if (eventlogAppender != null)
    {
        eventlogAppender.LogName = "MyLog";
        eventlogAppender.ActivateOptions();
        break;
    }
 }
```

You could add some tests to verify that there is only one EventLogAppender, but probably you do not need to bother to do so.

Comment: I want to change this value at runtime

Comment: I was missing the ActivateOptions() function call after making changes. Thanks!