# How to set log4net create filename with logger name and date?

Tags: c#

I would like to have files named for example:

loggername_yyyy-MM-dd.log

I try to possible:

```
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log\%logger_%date{yyyy-MM-dd}.txt" />
```

But he only take effect %date{yyyy-MM-dd}

How is this possible with log4net?

I want my different job use different logger, like : `ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("LogName");`, he should save to 'LogName_2019-03-07.log' file

The `%property{LogName}` only take effect in layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set log name in appender of log4net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530646/set-log-name-in-appender-of-log4net)

Comment: Are you saying you want each logger to write to a different file?

Comment: yes, my different job use different logger, like : "ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger("AnyJob");", i want this log save to 'AnyJob_2019-03-07.log' file

Comment: i try  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="Log\%property{LogName}.txt" />    but is null

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165084/log4net-rolling-daily-filename-with-date-in-the-file-name

Comment: i know possible by date, but i want it work by loggername