# Why is Log4Net ignoring my logName?

Tags: wcf, log4net, event-log, log4net-configuration

Okay so I have a WCF service writing to the Event Log.

All is well except for one detail..it won't pay any attention to the logName attribute,..here's the config.

```
    <!--EventLog Appender-->
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
        <logName value="MyCustomLog"/>
        <applicationName value="MyCustomEventSource" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

..and the initialization code.

```
        //Create an instance of the log from the declaring type.
        var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(0);
        log = LogManager.GetLogger(frame.GetMethod().DeclaringType);
        BasicConfigurator.Configure();
```

The event log does get written to but in the Application log (using the MyCustomEventSource" source) rather than my own.  Clearly I'm missing some important point but I don't see what that might be...  I'm running on Win 7 and IIS 7.5 if that makes any diff.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you create an [event source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412463/description-for-event-id-from-source-cannot-be-found/3414029#3414029)?

I am surprised that your code works: You need to use the `XmlConfigurator`. As far as I know the `BasicConfigurator` only configures a default console logger...

Maybe also consider to create the loggers like this (seems cleaner and shorter):

```
ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(YourClass));
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I was using the AssemblyInfo attribute using an XMLConfigurator. I marked you as correct since you pushed me in the right direction but my actual problem was that I had the event source registered to 2 separate logs.  It was only logging to the most recent.