# Visual studio crashes during test debugging with VSTTExecution cannot be found error

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

Visual studio crashes during test execution with VSTTExecution cannot be found error

I am running/debugging unit tests using visual studio 2013 but test crashes during debugging with following error on event viewer

```
The description for Event ID 0 from source VSTTExecution cannot be found. 
Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or 
the installation is corrupted. 
You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
```

How to repair this component?

Comment: Are you trying to connect to a test controller on a remote machine?  Also, does anything in here help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412463/description-for-event-id-from-source-cannot-be-found

Comment: @Taegost no i am running tests on my local machine.

Comment: Also i tried running VS in safemode and reset VS settings by devenv.exe/ResetSettings command but it still gives same error during test debug