# ASP.Net Core 1 Logging Error - The description for Event ID xxxx from source Application cannot be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, event-log

I would like to write to the Windows Event Log from an ASP.Net Core application's Controller method.

The issue I have is that, where I expect log information to be written I keep getting the error/information log:

> The description for Event ID **xxxx** from source Application cannot
>   be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed
>   on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can
>   install or repair the component on the local computer.
>
> If the event originated on another computer, the display information
>   had to be saved with the event.
>
> The following information was included with the event:
>
> My.Fully.Qualified.Namespace.WebApi.Controllers.MyController Error
>   occured in method 'MyMethod'
>
> the message resource is present but the message is not found in the
>   string/message table

As a quick note, prior to .Net Core, I had always [resolved a similar error by creating the Event Source using Powershell or Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412463/description-for-event-id-from-source-cannot-be-found) or properly configuring [Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging Application block](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569(v=pandp.50).aspx) or another third-party library

**Approach I used was:**

After installing the Nuget Packages: [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/) and [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/), I specify the [EventLog Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore1x#eventlog) in the Start Configure block of code.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory
            .AddDebug()
            .AddEventLog();

        //... rest of the code here
    }
```

**For each Controller, use the `ILogger<T>` approach**:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public MyController(IMyRepository myRepository,
        ILogger<MyController> logger)
    {
        _myRepository = myRepository;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public bool MyMethod(MyRequestObject request)
    {
        try
        {
            var response = privateDoSomethingMethod(request);

            return response.Success;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(6666,ex, "Error occured when doing stuff.");

            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is based on the [official documentation on Logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging?tabs=aspnetcore1x#eventlog)

What I have read and tried:

- [Description for event id from source cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412463/description-for-event-id-from-source-cannot-be-found)
- [IIS error -2147024809 when trying to run .NET CORE application](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/866)
- [When launching an ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 Web App in IIS 8.5 I get an HTTP500 and an Event 1001 against the HttpPlatformHandler](https://forums.asp.net/t/2080411.aspx?When%20launching%20an%20ASP%20NET%205%20MVC%206%20Web%20App%20in%20IIS%208%205%20I%20get%20an%20HTTP500%20and%20an%20Event%201001%20against%20the%20HttpPlatformHandler)
- [I​Logger Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger)
- [ASP.NET Core Logging Tutorial – What Still Works and What Changed?](https://stackify.com/asp-net-core-logging-what-changed/)

Comment: I was about to suggest you need to create the source which always used to fix this but see you tried that, I have used Serilog with dotnet core to write to the event log (not upgraded to 2.0 yet) so you could try it if all else fails.

Comment: EventViewer looks in binary files with compiled Windows MESSAGETABLE resources in them for the dictionary of id/strings.  How are you creating that binary file?

Comment: Hi @PeterRitchie, whilst this is a very old topic (over 5 years), I'm still failing to understand your question .This was an ASP.Net Core application. It's compiled code. Does that answer you?

Comment: Does your application have enough permissions to create the event source? Have you tried running as admin? (ouch, I see it's an old question, but still, my comment came from very old experience so it may apply ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to use the loggerFactory.AddEventLog() in .Net Core 2.0. As the Microsoft.Extensions.Logger.EventLog only lives in .net 4.5.1 although the Nuget package is available for 2.0.0 [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog/) , so looks like it needs to be ported to Core.

[image]

but maybe this will work for you.
Add your CustomEventIds

```
 public static class CustomEventIds
{
    public const int Debug = 100;
    public const int Information = 101;
    public const int Warning = 102;
    public const int Error = 103;
    public const int Critical = 104;
}
```

and:

```
_logger.LogInformation(CustomEventIds.Debug, "Starting to do something with input: {0}", "test");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I do already specify an Event Id.You can refer to the code.

Comment: If the OP was able to install the NuGet package, then **it is** available. NuGet doesn't let you install packages not available to your platform.

Comment: Here the [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1952) that says it is not available in core. You may consider calling an assembly at runtime that can do EventLogging for you see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465488/can-i-load-a-net-assembly-at-runtime-and-instantiate-a-type-knowing-only-the-na)

Comment: Generally, you would not want you API to create Windows event log messages as a caller could force enough event log messages to be created to cause the Windows server machine to run exceptionally slow.

Also, as others have pointed out, mix .NET core/.net 5 libraries with .net framework 4.7x/net standard libraries can cause problems.